# Intercept Ctrl and + as Win and +?

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

Is there an auto hotkey script or some preference somewhere where, in Windows 7, where I can intercept <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd> and replace with <kbd>Win</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd>? Also, an equivalent for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> being replaced with <kbd>Win</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In AutoHotKey:

```
^+::#+ ; Replace Ctrl-[plus] with Win-[plus]

^-::#- ; Do the same with Ctrl-[dash]
```

Note that the code above does not cover numpad plus and minus. For those, you need the following

```
^numpadadd::#numpadadd

^numpadsub::#numpadsub
```

Answer (score 1):

Win +/- acting like Ctrl +/-

```
LWin & +::
SendInput ^{+}
return

LWin & -::
SendInput ^{-}
return
```

Ctrl +/- acting like Win +/-

```
LCtrl & +::
SendInput #{+}
return

LCtrl & -::
SendInput #{-}
return
```

Answer (score 0):

Autoit Code:

```
HotKeySet("^{+}", "Transform1") ;captures [CTRL]+[+], Triggers Transform1
HotKeySet("^{-}", "Transform2") ;captures [CTRL]+[-], Triggers Transform2

While 1 ;while loop to keep processor from maxing out
    Sleep(100)
WEnd

Func Transform1() 
    ;Send("#{+}") ;sends [WIN]+[+]
EndFunc

Func Transform2()
    ;Send("#{+}") ;sends [WIN]+[-]
EndFunc
```