# In AutoHotKey scripts, is there a way to write modifiers in full

Tags: autohotkey

## Background

I have quite a few AutoHotKey scripts that are triggered by various combinations of <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> and some other key on the main keyboard.

For example, this (which I use to enter a DokuWiki level-1 heading into a text-editor):

```
+!1::
    Send, ======  ======
    Send, {Left}{Left}{Left}{Left}{Left}{Left}{Left}
Return
```

The problem I have is that I only use some of them rarely, and I find it really hard to easily remember what the abbreviations `^`, `;`, `+` and `#` mean.

(I am aware of this [table of Modifier key abbrevations](http://www.autohotkey.com/wiki/index.php?title=Standard_Windows_Hotkeys) - I just don't use them often enough to memorise them, and adding comments at the top of my scripts hasn't helped enough either.)

## Hoped-for improvement

Having seen examples like [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/328141/intercept-ctrl-and-as-win-and/328151#328151), I would like to change the script above to something like this, whose keyboard short-cut is immediately readable:

```
Shift & Alt & 1:: ; gives "invalid hotkey" error
    Send, ======  ======
    Send, {Left}{Left}{Left}{Left}{Left}{Left}{Left}
Return
```

However, the above gives me error, saying it is an "invalid hotkey". (I am using AutoHotKey 1.0.48.05)

I've tried various combinations, already, to no avail:

```
Shift & Alt & 1:: ; => invalid hotkey
Shift & Alt & {1}:: ; => invalid hotkey
Shift&Alt&1:: ; => does not exist in the current keyboard layout
Shift^Alt^1:: ; => does not exist in the current keyboard layout
```

Is there a way to correct the above list of keys, to be both readable and working, please?

**Edit: further experiments**

Having worked through the [table of modified symbols to define hotkeys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols), I've tried various additional combinations of named symbols, to try and understand what's allowed: none of them give the desired effect:

These are all OK (showing that named keys cam be used here - but they are not the hotkey I'm after):

```
Alt & 1::
Ctrl & 1::
Shift & 1::
LShift & 1::
```

These all give "invalid hotkey"

```
+ & Ctrl & 1::
+Ctrl & 1::
{~Shift} & 1::
{~Shift} & {~Alt} & 1::
~Shift & ~Alt & 1::
LShift & LAlt & 1::
LAlt & LShift & 1::
Shift & Alt & 1::
Alt & Shift & 1::
Ctrl & Alt & 1::
Shift & Alt & 1::
Shift & Alt & {1}::
1 & Shift & Alt::
```

And these all give "does not exist in the current keyboard layout"

```
Shift&Alt&1::
Shift^Alt^1::
Alt&1::
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I guess it stinks that those arbitrary symbols are used.  A self documenting macro is probably your best bet.

There has been talk in the AHK forums about an HTML documentor.  I'll see if I can dig up those posts also.